# What a weird operating range, 2.97V to 3.63V

Tags: microcontroller, ratings

I've seen several microcontrollers rated to operate from 2.97V to 3.63V. Others I've seen rated from 3V to 3.6V.

What's with the extra 30mV on either end of the scale? It doesn't seem like it would make any difference, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: It's a ridiculous spec that only shows that whoever wrote it doesn't understand beans about numbers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So that is 3V (with a 1% tolerance) to 3.6V (again with approx 1% tolerance)

OR

as Thomas O commented 3.3V +/- 10%

Comment: This makes the overall range ±10%.

Comment: No, 3.6 * 101% = 3.636, which rounds to 3.64.  It's 3.3 ±10%, and not 3.0 - 1% to 3.6+1%.  The two aren't equivalent.

Comment: @reem You can't round up maximum ratings, you will have to round it down.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that is just a precaution or tolerance.  Stating that if you run it at 3V its not the bottom of the scale, and you are safe there.

Comment: I think this is false.  You would need >30mV ripple to be 'safe', and, as Thomas O pointed out, it's just 3.3V ±10% (a contrived number). 'Safe' would be 3.3V, running near maxes or mins is dangerous.